# ionic and angular : json doesn't show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app with angular and a json file I would like to show up.

Here's what I have in my **www** folder :

```
--css
--img
--js
----app.js
----controller.js
--lib
--map
----dep.json
--vendors
index.html
```

Here's an ersatz of my *index.html*

```
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

<!-- svg map stuff -->
<link href="vendors/map/jqvmap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendors/map/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendors/map/jquery.vmap.france.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
[...]
<script id="templates/map.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Map">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Recherchez une ville, un code postal" ng-model="query">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-clear">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="CustomerController">
        <div id="francemap"style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="myName('Mowso')"> Click Me :) </button>
      </div>
      <div class="list-dep" ng-controller="DepListCtrl">
        <!--Body content-->

        <ul class="deps">
          <li ng-repeat="dep in deps | filter:query">
            <p>{{dep.code}} - {{dep.name}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div> 
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

As you can see it is an app with tabs. At first i put the data in the *controller.js* but now I want them in a json file but they don't appear on the screen anymore. my *controller.js* look like this :

```
 'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var map = angular.module('ionicApp');

/*map.controller('DepListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.deps = [
    {'code': '01', 'name': 'Ain'},
    {...},
    {'code': '974', 'name': 'Réunion'}
  ];
});*/

map.controller('DepListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('map/deps.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.dep = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

And all the data I have is in my json file (I commented them in the controller to keep a track of what i did before, basically they are the same in the json with more indentation).

I updated my nodejs yesterday but as I saw data disappeared I switch back to v4-4-4. I don't have any console error (I used to have one because I did not put my json in my map folder, silly me) and the *console.log(data)* in my controller show an array with all of my *deps*.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked which path it attempts to look up in the network log?

Comment: @Coss no I don't, now it's solved but I'll do that next time thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the property in your controller $scope.dep instead of $scope.deps

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an error in your path. You should use:

```
$http.get('./map/deps.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.dep = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

And in your source tree you have `dep.json` and in your controller you have `deps.json`. Please make sure those are also correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the `data` object returns other information to, like http status, headers etc. In `data.data` is the actual json you want.